# Is the election apparatus in Georgia run by Democrats?

Tags: united-states, politics, us-elections-2020

During a press conference around 6:30pm in Washington DC today on 5th of November 2020, President Trump stated that the election apparatus in Georgia is run by Democrats.

I have transcribed the quote with some context here:

> In Georgia a pipe burst in a far-away location, totally unrelated to
> the location of what was happening, and they stopped counting for 4
> hours. And a lot of things happened. **The election apparatus in Georgia
> is run by Democrats.**

This was at roughly 28:10 of [this video posted by Right Side Broadcasting Network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ni40sjwxjDg&t=1690).

What is the basis for this claim?

Comment: Does the US have some sort of concept of an Independent Electoral Commission (IEC) like we do in South Africa? If not, and voting is run by locals in every location, then how is this a meaningful claim? You could just as well make similar claims in all states.

Comment: Deleted comments that suggested it is inappropriate to ask questions here or attacked political views.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about what the right answer is. I've marked reirab's answer as it appears more complete, but also have no reason to think that jeffronicus' answer is wrong. I've found both answers to be really insightful in any case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**tl;dr:** For the relevant part of Georgia, **Yes, it is run by Democrats**, but this is not true for the state as a whole.

The majority of the work in elections in the United States is run by local election commissions, not by the state government (as Trump's quote seems to misleadingly suggest.) These are typically operated at the county level and appointed by county-level politicians. Thus, they are appointed by politicians who tend to reflect the political views of the individual counties, not of the state as a whole.

(For those not familiar with U.S. political systems, 'counties' are the political divisions beneath states, with each state typically being divided into many dozens of counties. According to the U.S. Geologic Survey, the 50 U.S. states plus District of Columbia (the capital district) are [divided into 3,141 counties or equivalents of counties](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-many-counties-are-united-states?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products). Very large cities may span a few counties, though most counties contain several smaller towns and cities.)

The bi-partisan [National Conference of State Legislatures](https://www.ncsl.org/aboutus.aspx) [describes the breakdown of work and oversight in running elections](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/election-administration-at-state-and-local-levels.aspx) in this way (emphasis mine):

> The U.S. is characterized by a highly decentralized election administration system. **The entities that do the rubber-meets-the-road functions of running an election are typically on the county or city/town level.** The state is responsible for certain aspects of elections as well, and the federal government has a role, too. The result is that no state administers elections in exactly the same way as another state, and there is quite a bit of variation in election administration even within states. Each state’s election administration structure and procedures grew organically, as times changed and administering an election became an increasingly complex task.

In general, there are some federal laws governing elections that all states and campaigns must follow. State laws define much more of the nuts and bolts of how elections should be run and a state-level agency typically oversees elections for the entire state and approves the final vote counts. However, the majority of the voting processes are defined by local-level election commissions and nearly all of the work of providing the means to vote and counting of the votes takes place under their direct oversight and according to their rules. They then report results up to the state-level election agency.

So, in a large, urban areas like Atlanta - where [every Mayor since 1879 has been a Democrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mayors_of_Atlanta) - **yes, most of the election apparatus is, in fact, run by Democrats.** Being much more populous than most Georgia counties, these are the counties where the vast majority of vote-counting over the last few days has still been taking place. The less populous counties, which tend to support and be run by Republicans, can typically complete their vote counting much sooner and most of that was done by election night. This is why Trump led Georgia by several percentage points late Tuesday night and his lead has been slowly declining since that time, ultimately switching to a very slight lead for Biden as of this morning (Friday, Nov 6.)

Note that this pattern is true in essentially all states that have any large cities, not just Georgia. The rural areas tend to be very conservative with local governments run by Republicans. Suburbs tend to be center-right with a mix of both Democratic and Republican-run governments, though somewhat favoring Republican-run ones. Large urban areas tend to be heavily Democratic with local governments run almost exclusively by Democrats. In all of those cases, the majority of the election apparatus is run by those local governments.

---

Edit: Another answer has added some incorrect information, so, to clear up the misconceptions mentioned in the other answer:

The "non-partisan" part of the Chairperson position on election boards in Georgia means that the position is not reserved to be nominated by one party or the other. It *does not* mean that the people who did nominate the Chairperson aren't from one party or the other or than the nominated Chairperson isn't from one party or the other.

For example, in Fulton County, Georgia's most populous county and the location of most of Atlanta, the election board has 5 members. Two are nominated by each party and [the other (the Chairperson) is appointed by the Fulton County Board of Commissioners](https://www.fultoncountyga.gov/inside-fulton-county/fulton-county-departments/registration-and-elections/registration-and-elections-board). Unsurprisingly, [the Fulton County Board of Commissioners has a Democratic majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulton_County,_Georgia#Government).

In particular, according to a contemporaneous [article from the Atlanta Journal-Constitution](https://www.ajc.com/news/local/fulton-consider-two-appointments-troubled-election-board/FGMs5uxgZnWGwyeXnulPII/), current Chairperson Mary Carole Cooney was nominated in 2013 by Democratic Fulton County Commissioner Robb Pitts:

> County Commissioner Robb Pitts, an Atlanta Democrat and former city councilman, nominated Cooney to chair the elections board. She spent 22 years as an attorney with the City of Atlanta. For the last 14 years she has been in private practice and since 2005 has served as secretary of the League of Women Voters of Atlanta-Fulton County.

The [website of the Registration and Elections Board](https://www.fultoncountyga.gov/inside-fulton-county/fulton-county-departments/registration-and-elections/registration-and-elections-board) confirms that she remains the Chairperson. While Ms. Cooney's position does not require her to officially state membership of a party, [her past campaign contributions](https://www.fec.gov/data/receipts/individual-contributions/?contributor_name=cooney%2C+mary&contributor_city=atlanta&max_date=12%2F31%2F2020) show that she has contributed repeatedly and exclusively to Democrats, including John Kerry, Barack Obama, [John Lewis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lewis), [Jim Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Martin_(Georgia_politician)) (who unsuccessfully ran for U.S. Senate in Georgia,) and others. It appears that she stopped contributing to political campaigns after her appointment to the election board. So, based on her own campaign contributions, the party of the commissioner who appointed her, and the fact that she was previously the Deputy City Attorney for Atlanta (which, as previously mentioned, has been run by Democrats continuously since the 1800s,) it seems fair to conclude that she's a Democrat.

This is not at all to suggest any wrongdoing on her part, nor that this situation is unusual. It almost certainly isn't. It's also not to suggest that the elections in Fulton County (or anywhere else) have been unfair. At least on a meaningful scale, that seems unlikely. But that isn't the subject of this question. This question is asking if the election apparatus is run by Democrats. Completely unsurprisingly, in Atlanta, it is. Just as it's almost certainly run by Republicans in the majority of Georgia's rural counties. Elections in the U.S. are run by the local governments and, thus, the people running them normally reflect the political views of the local population.

Comment: Thank you for providing a better explanation of this phenomenon than in my answer. The claim is undoubtedly true when measured in amount of control exerted over the total counting process... rather than number of election workers, which seems rather obtuse (and in fact backwards) of certain people to assume as the important metric.

Comment: It's still not clear why it is relevant, though. Are there any specific problems there, except that the votes coming from those counties are more towards Democrats?

Comment: @EricDuminil That's a good question, but it's not the one that was asked here. It would probably be best answered as a separate question, linking to this one for context.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, [election board of Fulton county](https://www.fultoncountyga.gov/inside-fulton-county/fulton-county-departments/registration-and-elections/registration-and-elections-board) (where Atlanta is located) consists of two democrats, two republicans, and a non-partisan chairman. So to say that it is "run by democrats" assumes that the non-partisan chairman is partisan. Is that your claim? Is so, what is it based on?

Comment: @Anders From the link you provided, "HB 656 returned the authority to select a Chairperson for the Registration and Elections Board to the Fulton County Board of Commissioners." The Fulton County Board of Commissioners [consists of 4 Democrats and 3 Republicans with a Democratic Chair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulton_County,_Georgia#Government).

Comment: @reirab Yes, but being selected by a democrat is not the same as being controled by a democrat. It could be, but it is still a case that needs to be made. Example: The swedish central bank board is selected by politicians, still anyone claiming "the central bank is run by party X" would be lying.

Comment: @Anders Updated to show that it is, in fact, controlled by Democrats.

Comment: "But that isn't the subject of this question." - Oh, but it is, because the notion that a counting center run by Democrats won't/can't count votes fairly is _exactly_ the implication that Trump is making.  A good answer would strongly refute this _first_, before getting into the vagaries about which party the staffers probably belong to and why.

Comment: @aroth my question was about whether the election apparatus in Georgia is run by Democrats, nothing more, nothing less. The question of what was implied is too complex so I intentionally didn't ask that. It would boil down to some variant of "Are Democrats committing systematic voter fraud in Georgia". That's a profoundly charged question, and probably impossible to prove or disprove in a forum like this. Feel free to ask that in a separate question, but I think it'll get closed.

Comment: Regardless of what you intended your question to ask, it was asked in a context where the president of the US is fraudulently claiming that an entire election is fraudulent just because they lost (and also is using SE to promulgate a 30-minute video from a politically biased source that's full of exactly those claims), using tangential factoids such as this one to back up their false (and evidence-free) claims of fraud.  A _good_ answer addresses that context, and makes it clear that in no way does the factoid being true imply that any of the associated claims are also true.

Comment: @aroth I think a good answer sticks to the point, and assumes of the reader the required level of maturity not to draw unnecessary implications from "factoids".

Answer (score 72):

Unclear what the basis for Trump’s claim is. Georgia Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger, who runs Georgia's Elections Division, is a Republican, as is the state’s governor.

[Republican Brad Raffensperger wins runoff for Georgia secretary of state](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/elections/republican-brad-raffensperger-wins-runoff-georgia-secretary-state-n943946) (Dec. 4, 2018)

> Raffensperger said he would continue Gov.-elect Brian Kemp's practice
> of strictly enforcing ID laws and pruning election rolls of inactive
> voters.

Addendum: Some of the other answers assert without evidence that the local election administrators in Georgia must be Democrats because urban areas where most of the votes are cast lean Democratic. (There is some cognitive dissonance in suggesting that the partisan tilt of a region is unfairly due to elected officials you assume are of one party because you're certain of the partisan tilt of the region.) Georgia elections are run under rules approved by the Republican-led legislature and overseen by a Republican-led elections board. Georgia's largest counties and apparently most, if not all, of the others have elections boards comprised of two Republican appointees, two Democrat appointees, and a non-partisan chairperson appointed by the county's executive committee. (Some boards are one of each party and three county-level appointees.) A detailed analysis of the county appointees might show a tilt one way or the other, but offhand this is hardly consistent with being "the election apparatus in Georgia is run by Democrats."

Comment: to me, this sounds less "unclear" and more like a plain "no". is there some aspect not (yet) included in your answer that makes you hesitate?

Comment: @nonthevisor It very much looks like no to me. However, the Trump campaign may make specific allegations if it brings suit in Georgia, and if that happens a complete answer would need to evaluate them.

Comment: to add, the current Governor (elected in 2018) was the previous Georgia Secretary of State who oversees the election (kind of an absurd function to oversee the election process you yourself are running in). but the entire state election administration is devised by the Republican Governor and Legislature.https://www.npr.org/2019/04/04/709911541/georgia-governor-signs-law-addressing-some-criticisms-of-contested-2018-election

Comment: While this may be true for the entire state, it’s not too much of a leap to think he was referring to the relevant areas to the situation right now (Atlanta, surrounding counties), where the elections are run by Democrats. I think this answer would be improved by mentioning that (and definitely not making it an outright “No”, as clearly a large portion of votes in Georgia are counted by Democratic officials).

Comment: @ChrisLoonam "Improving" the answer will rely on improving the claim.

Comment: "and a non-partisan chairperson appointed by the county's executive committee" Guess which party controls the executive committee... Maybe the one which has controlled the Mayor's office without gap for nearly 150 years? Also, my answer does not at all suggest anything about the partisan tilt of any region being 'unfair.' Trump may have suggested that, but I'm not. I strongly doubt that it is. But that wasn't the question that was asked. The fact is that the election apparatus in the Atlanta area (and a few other blue-leaning parts of Georgia) is indeed run primarily by Democrats.

Comment: *very large cities may span a few counties, though most counties contain several smaller towns and cities.)* Just to clarify for non-US readers, this means cities may *have parts in multiple counties,* i.e. they lie on the border between counties. Usually, they're mostly in one almost entirely. And it's not just large cities, my hometown is quite small, but happens to lie in two counties.

Answer (score 9):

No. The last time Georgia voted blue [was 1992](https://www.270towin.com/states/Georgia), for Bill Clinton's first term, and that's almost entirely explained by the [13.34% of Georgia voters](https://sos.ga.gov/elections/election_results/1992/pres.htm) who voted for Ross Perot. Currently, Georgia has a state government trifecta of the same political party, with control of the governor's office, the Georgia Senate, and the [Georgia House of Representatives](https://ballotpedia.org/Georgia_House_of_Representatives). Democrats have exactly zero influence over the way the state government, and by extension, its electoral apparatus, runs.

However, President Trump has a long history of accusing parties that do not bend to his will of partisanship. Examples include [Robert Mueller and his team of investigators](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-politics/wp/2018/03/18/trump-said-muellers-team-has-13-hardened-democrats-here-are-the-facts/), [Google](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/aug/28/trump-twitter-google-not-partisan-bias), and [Twitter](https://www.salon.com/2019/06/28/trump-accuses-twitter-of-censoring-him-in-bizarre-rant-on-fox-business_partner/).

Comment: You assert that those specific accusations are false without evidence.  There's a nontrivial amount of evidence suggesting that Twitter, for example, *is* somewhat partisan.  Asserting that it is not should require more than an empty claim.

Comment: I have removed the word 'falsely'. The articles most certainly show that he accuses people of partisanship *a lot*.

Comment: "Democrats have exactly zero influence over the way the state government, and by extension, its electoral apparatus, runs." This is completely false. Electoral commissions, not only in Georgia, but in every state, are run by the _local_ government, not the state government. The local governments in the Atlanta metro area (and nearly every other part of Georgia in which Biden leads) are run by Democrats.

Comment: Yeah, Democrats have office in Georgia, so that's plainly false and hyperbolic.

Answer (score -5):

In Georgia as in all states, the meaningful plurality of ballot-counting and other election machinery (weighted by number of votes, which is of course the important metric here) happens in cities and urban areas, which are therefore effectively run by people affiliated with the Democrat Party; it is possible that this the inference of the claim.

To explain this point: the general apparatus of (for example) who is responsible for manning the locations, hiring the volunteers, counting the votes, making decisions on how close observers should be etc. working in local circuit courts etc. in the case of disputes etc. are expected to come primarily from people living locally, which naturally over-samples from Democrat-voting areas.

For reference, the 11 counties of Atlanta city region have so far counted c.2.3M votes out of the total 4.9M votes across 159 counties. Source: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/11/03/us/elections/results-georgia.html

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  The vast majority of districts in Georgia voted predominantly for Trump.  Therefore people pulled in those areas working as election workers would by your logic be predominantly Republican voters.  What leads you to say they would be over-sampled Democrats?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the 'meaningful plurality of ballot counting and other election machinery' happens in cities and urban areas?  Doesn't each district count and report separately?

Comment: Of 159 counties in Georgia, only 29 have Biden leading. Assuming some minimum number of election personnel in each county, you'd expect to see that people from red counties are over-represented among election personnel. A county that gets 100x as many ballots likely does not require 100x as many personnel to process them.

Comment: Skeptics.SE requires sources, no matter how obvious or dubious the claim

Comment: To answer your question, I am referrng to  the number of votes. For example, c.20% of total votes from those 159 counties came from just the counties of Atlanta, just for context

Comment: Source added, thanks. And having double checked it's more like 45%

Comment: @Zac I don't see how that figure supports your point. You're suggesting that 11 counties  counting 2.3M votes requires more election workers than 148 counties counting 2.6M votes, when it's likely the opposite. Smaller districts are likely to be less personnel-efficient since they cannot take advantage of economy of scale.

Comment: Yes I see your point on that one Mr Hoagie, butI'm playing devil's advocate here because I think Trump usually needs translating into English. I believe that someone saying "the Georgia election apparatus is run by Democrats" most likely means to say that "the Democrat party have sufficient control around the voting process in Georgia that they (alone) could tilt the result". The justification for such a belief could be that only one or two corrupted locations in the right places (e.g. disenfranchise just 1% of Fulton County's votes and get away with it)

Comment: ...would be sufficient to do this, which doesn't apply in the rural areas

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Actually... it can make sense. That's the point of having decentralization in some cases; it's just more efficient. Large bureaucracies are notorious for running poorly, with a bunch of redundancy and wasted resources...

Comment: Okay, I think get what the answer meant. Democrats at the federal level are more likely to have direct control of a few key counties at the local level that amount here to nearly 50% of the vote than Republicans on the counties that lean Republican since Republicans would have to be managing 15 times more counties.